# SVN diff with revision range and changelists

Tags: svn, diff, changelist

I'm having some troubles with SVN changelists and `svn diff`. Particularly I want to obtain the change history of a certain list of files for a specified range of revisions.
SVN changelists seem like the perfect solution, so my approach was:

- `svn changelist LIST a.txt b.txt d.txt ...`
- `svn diff --changelist LIST --revision 2:3`

Unfortunately, this includes all files, even those not on the changelist. Using the same syntax without `--revision` works perfectly well.

I suspect that changelists are designed for the working copy only and aren't considered for history stuff at all. If so, what would the simplest alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SVN book [chapter on changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.changelists):

> The --changelist option acts only as a
>   filter for Subversion command targets,
>   and will not add targets to an
>   operation

If you substitute the `--changelist` option for the actual list of files, say `a.txt b.txt d.txt ...` you get the desired output. I guess the behaviour of the command is to use current working copy directory as the target and then it is simply unable to apply the filter for the changelist.

Comment: Substituting `--changelist` is indeed a smart idea, I hadn't considered that. Thanks!